# Cypress component testing is not loading CSS while running testcases

Tags: testing, automation, components, cypress

We are building web components using stencil. We compile the stencil components and create respective "React component" and import them into our projects.

While doing so we are able to view the component as expected when we launch the react app. However when we mount the component and execute test cases using cypress we observe that the CSS for these pre built components are not getting loaded.

**cypress.json**

```js
    {
        "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
        "projectId": "263jf8",
        "component": {
            "componentFolder": "src",
            "testFiles": "**/*spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "viewportHight": 1200,
            "viewportWidth": 1000
        },
        "retries": {
            "runMode": 2,
            "openMode": 0
        }
    }
```

**sample spec file**

```js
import Header from './header'; 
describe('header', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        mount(
            <Header></Header>
        )})
        it('renders as an inline button', () => {
             cy.get('button')
             .should('have.class', 'nexus-btn').and('be.visible')
             cy.get('.nexus-hamburger-icon').should('have.text','Close Menu').and('be.visible')
             cy.get('.nexus-menu > .nexus-btn').should('have.text','Close Menu')
             cy.get('a > .nexus-visually-hidden').contains('Home')
             cy.contains('Home').should('exist')
             cy.get('a > .nexus-icon > svg').should('be.visible')
            })
        })
```

**plugin/cypress.index.js**

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('cypress-grep/src/plugin')(config)

  if (config.testingType === 'component') {
    require('@cypress/react/plugins/react-scripts')(on, config)
  }
  return config

}
```

**Expected**
[image]

**Actual**
[image]

Comment: I might be wrong but if you will follow this article https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/cypress-component-testing-react/
and use suggestion for `cypress/plugins/index.js` it can work as you expected. But reproduce your case need more details better link to playground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try importing the css in the `index.ts` or `index.js` file that will be available in the location `cypress/support/index.ts`

Comment: Thanks @Sivanandhini . This works for me

Comment: This definitely helped me! Also for anyone using tailwindcss my component-index.html file was not listed in my content array in tailwind.config.js. These two things solved my issue!

Comment: Can someone post a working example? It does not work for me. I'm using Ionic React and I copied all css imports over to component.ts without any effect